# How many gods are there in oWoD?

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness

I'm looking for a comprehensive listL

- I know there is THE God, who made Angels, kicked some of them out of heaven thus making Fallen and left, bored with the state of things.
- There are Egyptian Gods, being core part of Mummy splats and in some way also Vampire splats.
- Werewolf splats have Celestines. Gaia, Wyrm, etc.
- Ascended Mages / Archmages are technically gods, since they can create their own universes.
- There are also Outer Gods, pretty much Great Old Ones equivalent.

But what else?
Can I assume Gods from other mythologies (greek/roman, celtic, norse) are also present?
And where do Fey end up on the godly scale? They are designed as mythical part of the setting after all.

Comment: Depends how you define "god". For example, a lot of pagan deities from around the world are secretly ancient vampires. Do they count as gods or not? (And if they do, what about all the other various fourth-gens out there?)

Comment: Yeah, there is a whole score of spirit entities that are "god-tier" and some ancient supernatural creatures might also be worshipped as gods. Earthbound Fallen have their own cults. The only answer is "numerous" but that's both because there are too many to count, as well as just because we *can't* count them as "god" is rather ill-defined. Also depending on how you define them the Wyrm is probably not a god. Just a cosmic force. It's like trying to claim gravity is a god.

Comment: Where's your line for god? Incarna? Forces of creation?

Comment: As a random example, Odin is a 5th generation Gangrel.

Comment: I always saw Wyrm/Weaver/Wyld as, well, anthropomorphizations of observed metaphysic interactions. Kind of like "a wagon pulling the sun around the earth", the effects match up the myths, but the myths do not properly describe the underlying reality of gravity. There is no "Wyrm" entity, so much as effects which are currently ascribed to it. Gaia is explicitly the spirit of Earth, which (arguably) makes her not a God, neither. The line is a weird one in WoD, however - look at 4th gen Ur-shulgi; its character sheet contains the phrase "do such trappings matter to a god?".

Comment: @From indeed very blurry line. The metaphysic trinity of Change/Stasis/Destruction or Wyld/Weaver/Wyrm is quite heavily implied to just be *things* or forces. Not entities or some sort of agents that act with any intent. Although some sources try to ascribe *thinking* to these. Particularly there are few mentions of the Weaver being the first to gain some sort of sapience. Which is what caused it to trap the Wyrm *inside* the universe. Now, whether that's true or not - the Wyrm being trapped by the Weaver does make it more of an entity. Some sources do still claim still a force of nature.

Comment: Isn't there also something in the Demon: the Fallen book about there being different realities at some point, so that millions of years of evolution and seven days of creation are both true? Which would mean that even within the lore itself, the number of gods might not be fixed.

Comment: @DvdZee yes, that's the lore of Demon. It attempted to bridge all possible origin stories and histories from the other older gamelines. Of course, it still means things contradict themselves and aren't quite clear but at least there is was an official explanation for why.